# ListView no devuelve el elemento seleccionado después de filtrar

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un `ListView` con elementos y realizo un filtro a través de un `EditText` pero al hacer click en uno de los elementos de la lista resultante (lista filtrada) el elemento seleccionado no se devuelve, sino el elemento que antes del filtro tenia esa posición.

//Selección de elementos

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(miContexto,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaBienes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         bienSelect = listaBienes.get(position);
         intention.putExtra("bien_select", bienSelect);
         startActivity(intention);
     });
```

//Busqueda de elementos

```
     buscar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         }

         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Para seleccionar el elemento que esta dando click **es importante usar la variable `position`**, contiene el valor del indice del elemento seleccionado, estas realizando correctamente esta parte.

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           bienSelect = listaBienes.get(position);
...
...
```

**si estas obteniendo un elemento antiguo en esa posición significa que tu array `listaBienes` en realidad tiene elementos antiguos.**

Asegura que `listaBienes` tenga los valores deseados.

"Que la fuerza te acompañe"!

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo revisaré

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el problema, estaba tomando la posición del arreglo mientras deberia tomar la del adapter.
    bienSelect = adapter.getItem(position);

Comment: esto no deberia ser una respuesta,  por favor eliminela e edite su pregunta en todo caso